# What happens if I update/insert data into a table that is ignored from replication in Slave DB?

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

I have setup Master-Slave replication in MySQL 5.1 and the table "sessions"  is ignored for replication ( --replicate-ignore-table=ak.sessions ). What happens if I update/insert data into sessions tables in Slave DB? Will the replication still continue? or will it stop the replication process with the error?

Comment: Why you want to add data directly in slave ? Even if you are not replicating the session table into slave the add should not hamper but what if you need to activate the replication for the table ? This will be a disaster. The rule is master is for insert/update and slave is for select.

Comment: Thank you Abhik. Problem in my case is, I am using a legacy framework that was built with only Master DB in mind. And now with master/slave in place, I want to separate reads to slave and writes to master. But this framework mandatorily updates sessions table for every mysql_connect. So, if I connect to Slave, it updates sessions in Slave.

Comment: Or is there any way, via mysql configuration, to bifurcate reads to slave and writes to master? (except application code change)

Comment: No, I faced the same problem with Vtiger CRM and I had to re-write their sql connection object. An idea would be to create 2 DB connection one for master and one for slave. You must have some `query` function and there you can detect if its select or insert/update/delete and execute it on related server.

Comment: Oh alright. I was looking for a quick fix alternative other than altering their core library. It now seems that I have to alter it anyway :). No other option I guess.

Comment: Doctrine has master-slave replication setup, you can use that in future.

Comment: Thank you Abhik. Please put your suggestion as Answer. Let me accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The master-slave replication rule thumb is `master` is for `insert/update/delete` and slave is for select.

So by definition when any `insert/update/delete` happens it will be replicated to slave. Now we need to make sure that we never do `insert/update/delete` on slave since the reverse is not possible and this will lead to potential disaster.

Some of the PHP library for DB provides master slave setup like **[Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connections.MasterSlaveConnection.html)**.

However if you choose to write custom DB handler then you may need to create 2 connections one for master and one for slave and use them to execute the query depending on query type.

Comment: Can you provide some insight into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43849283/fetch-inserted-data-in-master-slave-model ?

Comment: @emilly you have an answer by someone and thats the correct approach, if you do immediate invocation after insert/update depending on the network speed and how fast the replication happens its always better to do the select from master. Thats one of the strategy in heavy traffic site use. So say you have an api and someone added some data into DB and you want to return the last inserted data in response its wise to do select on master than slave just to make sure the replication lag does not create the confusion.